# Equation of parabola whose ends of latus rectum are $(-1,2)$ and $(5,2)$

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I found the distance between ends using distance formula i.e $6$. 
$\Rightarrow 4a => $
$a= 3/2$
and the focus $(2,2) $
What should I do next? How to use this information in $(x-h)^2 = -4a(y-k)^2$

Comment: "Inculcate" means to instill an attitude by persistent instruction. Do you mean calculate?

Answer (score 0):

HINT... based on what you have done, you can deduce that the vertex has coordinates $\left(2, \frac 12\right)$.